# GIT author authentication

Tags: git, security

Our company is looking into modernize our version control and generally we would like to use git. I've use distributed version control before but only with personal project and opensource project (where there is some sort of user management) (Mercurial on Google code and Bazaar on LaunchPad). I am not sure about how can we authenticate author of each commit if we are using GIT on our own repository. I am not talking about the authentication for push but for commit.

So let say ..
1. I clone the repo and check out a branch.
2. I change my user.name to my worker and make changes and finally commit.
3. I change my user.name back and push (with my ssh account for example).
4. There I can blame all the changes to my coworker.

Will this be a problem? How do we get around to tame this problem?

I am sure there is something out there but I guess I am not looking for the right info so it would be very helpful if you guys can give me some basic overview on this.

Thanks

Comment: Is this an actual problem? I've been working at a fairly large company where we use git for version control and gerrit for code reviews. Never has the question of spoofed commit authors/committers popped up. Sometimes people mistakingly put themselves as the author when doing a cherry-pick, but that's usually caught during code review.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It is not a problem now as we are still evaluating. It is corporate policy and paranoia that is in the play here. Also, I sense that they will not like that we have to rely solely on code reviewer (as mistake can happen in case of complex branch where many people have hand on).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot regulate the creation of commits, since that happens on each user's workstation, in their own local copy of the repository.

You can do some checks (with hooks) in the central repository, and require that incoming commits bear the name of the connecting user.  **However, this is a bad idea.**

Consider the case where one user might need to reuse someone else's work, but doesn't want to merge it.  He might cherry-pick someone else's commit, or rebase their branch onto his own.  In this case, it is **correct** that the authorship information match the original commits, and restricting incoming commits to have an author name that matches the user pushing them would break this workflow.

I would worry about this only if it becomes a problem.  It comes down to trust: if you don't trust a developer, why do they work for you?

Comment: Actually it is not company I own and there are about a hundred of people here so the corporate infrastructure and certain management persons concerns about accountability.

Comment: @NawaMan If you want the flexibility and agility of Git, then you can't impose this restriction.  If your company wants to centrally manage everything and impose restrictions, then don't use a decentralized VCS.  Or, require code reviews for Git pushes.

Comment: You can always require signing commits with a user's private key. But I would say this is all over the top. You can use server-side hooks to make sure users are restricted to committing a given name/email only, but as cdhowie rightly points out this makes it difficult to commit other people's work in certain workflows.

Comment: @MikeWeller That would fail in rebase/cherry-pick scenarios too, unless we are authenticating the *committer* field and not the *author* field.  (And since the commit itself changes, the signature would be invalidated anyway.)

Comment: I haven't used git commit signing, but I would assume in that case you could use the signing information to know who actually made the commit. If someone claims to have been impersonated, you look at the signing info.

Comment: @MikeWeller I see -- so cherry-picked commits would have to be resigned.  That would work, if authentication is indeed required.

Comment: Thanks you all. I will look into the signing commit.